# Input field to show X in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, string

Hello I am using Angular and typescript, I am trying to hide the first 8 characters that the user is inputting and show the remaining 4.

Edit - Added Stackblitz link [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-welcome-app-r9vhgg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
<input type="text" [value]="maskedInput" (input)="onInput($event)" maxlength="12">
<p>Masked: {{ maskedInput }}</p>
<p>Unmasked: {{ unmaskedInput }}</p>
```

The problem is that the input field is getting masked properly and showing the masked version. However the unmasked is also showing the masked version.

```
  maskedInput: string = '';
  unmaskedInput: string = '';
  digitsBeforeMasking: string = '';
  onInput(event: any) {
    this.unmaskedInput = event.target.value;
    this.digitsBeforeMasking = this.unmaskedInput.substring(0, 8);
    this.maskedInput = this.digitsBeforeMasking.replace(/\d/g, 'X') + this.unmaskedInput.substring(8);
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thank you!

Comment: Please share a live repro, using Stackblitz would be nice but any other may do. That'll help people digging into your issue a lot faster and eventually fork it to try new things on their side before coming back to you. It's a really great to let the community help you

Comment: thank you @maxime1992, i have added the proper link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version is using this input where [value] cannot be 2 ways bind.

```
<input type="text" [value]="maskedInput" (input)="onInput($event)" maxlength="12">
```

I suggest you to use a ngModel or a *formcontrolname if you are inside a form

The input you should use with ngModel

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="unmaskedInput" (input)="onInput($event)" maxlength="12">
```

Here is a the corrected stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-welcome-app-3r39kn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html